# How to set glPointSize in Processing 2.2.1 using GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, processing

I was looking at [POINT_SIZE](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glEnable#.28GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE.29) in draw OpenGL but I'm now sure how to access the constants to get POINT_SIZE in Processing.

After quickly skimming the [Processing javadocs](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/) I've tried enabling [ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/opengl/PGL.html#ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE) like so:

```
pgl.enable(PGL.ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE);
```

but I got this error:

```
OpenGL error 1280 at top endDraw(): invalid enumerant
```

What I've tried is simply modifying the LowLevelGL example from Examples > Demos > Graphics:

```
// Draws a triangle using low-level OpenGL calls.
import java.nio.*;

PGL pgl;
PShader sh;

int vertLoc;
int colorLoc;

float[] vertices;
float[] colors;

FloatBuffer vertData;
FloatBuffer colorData;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P3D);
  // Loads a shader to render geometry w/out
  // textures and lights.
  sh = loadShader("frag.glsl", "vert.glsl");

  vertices = new float[12];
  vertData = allocateDirectFloatBuffer(12);

  colors = new float[12];
  colorData = allocateDirectFloatBuffer(12);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  // The geometric transformations will be automatically passed 
  // to the shader.
  rotate(frameCount * 0.01, width, height, 0);

  updateGeometry();

  pgl = beginPGL();
  sh.bind();

  pgl.enable(PGL.ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE);

  vertLoc = pgl.getAttribLocation(sh.glProgram, "vertex");
  colorLoc = pgl.getAttribLocation(sh.glProgram, "color");

  pgl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertLoc);
  pgl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLoc);

  pgl.vertexAttribPointer(vertLoc, 4, PGL.FLOAT, false, 0, vertData);
  pgl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLoc, 4, PGL.FLOAT, false, 0, colorData);

  pgl.drawArrays(PGL.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

  pgl.disableVertexAttribArray(vertLoc);
  pgl.disableVertexAttribArray(colorLoc);

  sh.unbind();  

  endPGL();
}

void updateGeometry() {
  // Vertex 1
  vertices[0] = 0;
  vertices[1] = 0;
  vertices[2] = 0;
  vertices[3] = 1;
  colors[0] = 1;
  colors[1] = 0;
  colors[2] = 0;
  colors[3] = 1;

  // Corner 2
  vertices[4] = width/2;
  vertices[5] = height;
  vertices[6] = 0;
  vertices[7] = 1;
  colors[4] = 0;
  colors[5] = 1;
  colors[6] = 0;
  colors[7] = 1;

  // Corner 3
  vertices[8] = width;
  vertices[9] = 0;
  vertices[10] = 0;
  vertices[11] = 1;
  colors[8] = 0;
  colors[9] = 0;
  colors[10] = 1;
  colors[11] = 1;

  vertData.rewind();
  vertData.put(vertices);
  vertData.position(0);

  colorData.rewind();
  colorData.put(colors);
  colorData.position(0);  
}

FloatBuffer allocateDirectFloatBuffer(int n) {
  return ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(n * Float.SIZE/8).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
}
```

vert.glsl:

```
/*
  Part of the Processing project - http://processing.org

  Copyright (c) 2011-12 Ben Fry and Casey Reas

  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License version 2.1 as published by the Free Software Foundation.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General
  Public License along with this library; if not, write to the
  Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330,
  Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 */

uniform mat4 transform;

attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec4 vertColor;

void main() {
  gl_PointSize = 200.0;
  gl_Position = transform * vertex;    
  vertColor = color;
}
```

frag.glsl:

```
/*
  Part of the Processing project - http://processing.org

  Copyright (c) 2011-12 Ben Fry and Casey Reas

  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License version 2.1 as published by the Free Software Foundation.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General
  Public License along with this library; if not, write to the
  Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330,
  Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 */

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

varying vec4 vertColor;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vertColor;
}
```

My question explicitly is what Processing object would I need to access to enable POINT_SIZE and how would I change the size in from a GLSL shader ?

Comment: I can't really answer your question since I don't know anything about Processing. But I'm pretty sure that `ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE` is not something you enable; it's a value to be queried. It's how you ask the context what the range of valid sizes for aliased points is.

Comment: Are you asking how to access it on client side or gpu side?

Comment: @TheRealNox I imagine I would need to enable ton the client side then use it on the gpu side ? Would be great to know how to do use this on both sides. (If you could point me in the right direction, that would help)

Answer (score 2):

Try to check your OpenGL version of your context because **`GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE`** and **`GL_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY`** are deprecated in GL versions 1.2 and greater. Their functionality has been replaced by **`GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE`** and **`GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY`**.

Comment: What's the easiest way to do that ?
I've tried doing this:```println(pgl.VERSION,pgl.SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);```which prints ```7938 35724```. I'm still an OpenGL n00b so that's where part of the confusion, but the other part figuring out how to do from OpenGL docs (c++ API) to JOGL to Processing [PJOGL](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/opengl/PJOGL.html) use a feature I find the original OpenGL docs via Processing. For example, I can't figure out what class would have the ```GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE``` constant

Comment: I am not sure but `pgl.VERSION` may give you library version not the OpenGL version. I just looked at PGL source at github and found some function which may be useful `boolean isES()` and `int[] getGLVersion()`. Also you may need to use `glEnable( GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE );` to enable feature.

Comment: the tricky parts are I can't find the ```GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE``` constant and the ```isES()``` and ```getGLVersion()``` methods are protected :/ (thank you by the way for taking your time to look into it +1)

Comment: @George I have no idea what I'm talking about (shaders are black magic to me), but if all you're looking for is the `GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE` variable, it's in the `com.jogamp.opengl.GL3` interface. You can import that and then use `GL3.GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE`. For me that prints out `34370`.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks for sharing that, I'll give that a go. As a hacky workaround I could draw a circle in GLSL (similar to how [this guy does it](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xlt3R8)) with a varying radius, but it would be nice to learn how to use the built in functionality to change how a vertex is rendered.

Comment: @George Again, no idea if this is useful or not, but the `com.jogamp.opengl` package also contains a `GLContext` class. From that you can do something like this: `GLContext.getCurrentGL().getGL3().glEnable(GL3.GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);` Dunno if that's right, but combing through the [JOGL JavaDocs](https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/) might get you somewhere.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I'll have play